# How to create Gitlab webhook to receive post or get request from other webapp

Tags: gitlab, webhooks, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to receive a call back to run a gitlab runner script from third party webapp which I can register a webhook URL, but I cannot find any documentation about it.

I am wondering if this is even possible to create a webhook address to receive post request and process the request body.

Where can I find the documentation or implementation sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> run a gitlab runner script from third party webapp

If by runner script you mean project pipeline then you can use [API triggers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/)

You can add trigger in Project `Settings -> CI/CD -> Pipeline triggers`